# Add values in columns if criteria from another column is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'Client':[1,2,3,4],'Salesperson':['John','John','Bob','Richard'], 
     'Amount':[1000,1000,0,500],'Salesperson 2':['Bob','Richard','John','Tom'],
     'Amount2':[400,200,300,500]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

| Client | Salesperson | Amount | Salesperson | Amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1000 | Bob | 400 |
| 2 | John | 1000 | Richard | 200 |
| 3 | Bob | 0 | John | 300 |
| 4 | Richard | 500 | Tom | 500 |

And I just need to create some sort of "sumif" statement (the one from excel) that will add the amount each salesperson is due. I don't know how to iterate over each row, but I want to have it so that it adds the values in "Amount" and "Amount2" for each one of the salespersons.

Then I need to be able to see the amount per salesperson.

Expected Output (Ideally in a DataFrame as well)

| Sales Person | Total Amount |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2300 |
| Bob | 400 |
| Richard | 700 |
| Tom | 500 |

Comment: Please also post your expected output.

Comment: Okay I added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be multiple ways of solving this. One option is to use `Pandas Concat` to join required columns and use groupby

```
merged_df = pd.concat([df[['Salesperson','Amount']], df[['Salesperson 2', 'Amount2']].rename(columns={'Salesperson 2':'Salesperson','Amount2':'Amount'})])
merged_df.groupby('Salesperson',as_index = False)['Amount'].sum()
```

you get

```
    Salesperson Amount
0   Bob         400
1   John        2300
2   Richard     700
3   Tom         500
```

Edit: If you have another pair of salesperson/amount, you can add that to the concat

```
d = {'Client':[1,2,3,4],'Salesperson':['John','John','Bob','Richard'], 
     'Amount':[1000,1000,0,500],'Salesperson 2':['Bob','Richard','John','Tom'],
     'Amount2':[400,200,300,500], 'Salesperson 3':['Nick','Richard','Sam','Bob'],
     'Amount3':[400,800,100,400]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

merged_df = pd.concat([df[['Salesperson','Amount']], df[['Salesperson 2', 'Amount2']].rename(columns={'Salesperson 2':'Salesperson','Amount2':'Amount'}), df[['Salesperson 3', 'Amount3']].rename(columns={'Salesperson 3':'Salesperson','Amount3':'Amount'})])
merged_df.groupby('Salesperson',as_index = False)['Amount'].sum()

    Salesperson Amount
0   Bob         800
1   John        2300
2   Nick        400
3   Richard     1500
4   Sam         100
5   Tom         500
```

Edit 2: Another solution using `pandas wide_to_long`

```
df = df.rename({'Salesperson':'Salesperson 1','Amount':'Amount1'}, axis='columns')
reshaped_df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Salesperson','Amount'], i='Client',j='num', suffix='\s?\d+').reset_index(drop = 1)
```

The above will reshape df,

```
    Salesperson Amount
0   John    1000
1   John    1000
2   Bob     0
3   Richard 500
4   Bob     400
5   Richard 200
6   John    300
7   Tom     500
8   Nick    400
9   Richard 800
10  Sam     100
11  Bob     400
```

A simple groupby on reshaped_df will give you required output

```
reshaped_df.groupby('Salesperson', as_index = False)['Amount'].sum()
```

Comment: This isn't working, for some reason it's only adding some of the values and not all of them.

Comment: What values is it not adding? Is there a mismatch in column names between your actual dataframe and the one you shared here?

Comment: 1000 for John. It's only giving me 1300. If the actual values I have are floats and not ints could that affect something?

Comment: I think I figured out what is happening. If the name is consecutive it won't add it. John appears consecutively in row 1 and row 2, so it ignores the second row for some reason.

Comment: The second one works!

Comment: How would I add more salesperson and amount if I wanted to in the second one?

Comment: pandas concat takes list of dataframes as argument so you can add another pair of salesperson/amount to concat

Comment: And my bad on option 1, it won't work as dictionaries should have unique keys. Removing that solution

Comment: What exactly is the "rename" doing? I'm doing what you did for more pairs but it seems to only be taking the last two. Could you maybe put on example here in the comment section in which you add another "Salesperson 3" and "Amount3"? Thank you very much for everything!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to tidy the dataframe into long form, where all the Salespersons are in one column, and the amounts are in another, then you can groupby and get the aggregate.

Let's use [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to transform to long form:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
.pivot_longer(
     index="Client",
     names_to=".value",
     names_pattern=r"([a-zA-Z]+).*",
     )
.groupby("Salesperson", as_index = False)
.Amount
.sum()
)

  Salesperson  Amount
0         Bob     400
1        John    2300
2     Richard     700
3         Tom     500
```

The `.value` tells the function to keep only those parts of the column that match it as headers. The columns have a pattern (They start with a text - either Salesperson or Amount - and either have a number at the end ( or not). This pattern is captured in `names_pattern`. `.value` is paired with the regex in the brackets, those outside do not matter in this case.

Once transformed into long form, it is easy to groupby and aggregate. The `as_index` parameter allows us to keep the output as a dataframe.